# there is no text in radio buttons on screen

Tags: java, radio-button, android-studio-3.1

> in this program, I want to show on screen radio buttons with rooms name

```
buttonList = new RadioButton[roomNames.length];
btGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.roomList);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;
for(int i = 0; i < roomNames.length; i++)
    {
        //buttonList[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        RadioButton tempBT = new RadioButton(this);
        System.out.println("room name number :"+ i + roomNames[i]);
        rprms= new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //tempBT.setText(roomNames[i].subSequence(0,roomNames[i].length()));
        //tempBT.setTextColor(0);
        tempBT.setId(i);
        buttonList[i] = tempBT;
        btGroup.addView(tempBT, rprms);
        //buttonList[i].setText(roomNames[i].subSequence(0,roomNames[i].length()));
        //buttonList[i].setTextColor(0);
        //btGroup.addView(buttonList[i], rprms);
    }
    for (int f = 0; f < btGroup.getChildCount(); f++) {
        ((RadioButton) btGroup.getChildAt(f)).setText(roomNames[f].subSequence(0,roomNames[f].length()));
        ((RadioButton) btGroup.getChildAt(f)).setTextColor(0);
    }

    //saving the chosen room name
    btGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId) {
            for(int j = 0; j < buttonList.length; j++)
            {
                if(btGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == buttonList[j].getId())
                {
                    roomNameSelected = roomNames[j];
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

> but when I run this program I see the radio buttons but there is no text inside

Comment: Could it be because of `setTextColor(0)` part? Try `setTextColor(Color.BLACK)`

Comment: Wow yes, it worked! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
setTextColor(0);
```

Try

```
setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```